# Grouping multiple column operations in 1 table scan

Tags: sql, postgresql, sas

I need to translate SAS code (`PROC SQL`) to (postgres) SQL, especially the `calculated` keyword in SAS that allow a variable defined in the query to be re-used directly in the same query for another variable computation:

```sql
SELECT 
     id,
     sum( case
         when (sales > 0) then 1
         when (sales = 0) then 0
         else -1 
     end) as pre_freq,
     (case 
         when calculated pre_freq > 0 then calculated pre_freq 
         else 1 
     end) as freq
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

This is not possible (AFAIK) in SQL, so I need to break down each step of the computation.

I was wondering what was the best option, knowing that, from my understanding, it is better to have more computations and fewer table scans, i.e. make as much as computation during a scan, instead of multiple table scans with a small computation steps.

In this particular exemple I could use:

```sql
SELECT 
       id
     , greatest(1, sum( case
         when (sales > 0) then 1
         when (sales = 0) then 0
         else -1 
     end) as freq
FROM 
     my_table
GROUP BY id
```

or:

```sql
SELECT 
       id
       , (case when sum(case
                when (sales > 0) then 1
                when (sales < 0) then -1 
                else 0
        end) > 0 then sum(case
                when (sales  > 0) then 1
                when (sales  < 0) then -1 
                else 0
        end) else 1 end) as freq
FROM 
     my_table
GROUP BY id
```

... which is starting to be hard to read...

- Is there anyway to define a variable for a snippet of SQL code that will be repeated?
- More generally speaking that this illustration, was is the best (most efficient) approach?

Comment: Add new column that will represent those 1, -1 and 0 flags ... then just sum them

Comment: Both of you alternatives need to be grouped by `id`. I don't know about SAS's. Is that what you want? `freq` by `id`?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto yes indeed for both sas & sql. edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calculated` is a nice feature of `proc sql`.  However, you cannot re-use aliases in databases in general (this is not a Postgres-specific limitation).  A simple method is to use a subquery or CTE:

```
select id, pre_freq,
       (case when pre_freq > 0 then pre_freq 
             else 1 
        end) as freq
from (select id,
             sum(case when (sales > 0) then 1
                      when (sales = 0) then 0
                      else -1 
                 end) as pre_freq,
      from my_table t
      group by id
     ) t;
```

However, the simplest solution is to use `sign()`:

```
select id, sum(sign(sales)) as pre_freq,
       greatest(sum(sign(sales)), 1) as freq
from my_table t
group by id;
```

Note:  This is slightly different.  It basically ignores `NULL` values.  If you really need to treat `NULL` as -1, then use `coalesce()`.

Comment: I guess you meant `greatest` instead of `least` (?). And would you confirm my understanding that a CTE (involving 2 table 'scans') will be longer to process than one simple scan (in this example)?

Comment: @ant1j Although a certain CTE can be semantically equivalent to a certain subquery the planner can't optimize for the former.